# How do I insert a single field static data along with multiple (field)row dynamic data into MySQL database from PHP form

Tags: php, mysql, forms

****NOTE**: I have asked a similar question on this site but I have done extensive edit to the initial question to the extent I believe it warrants submission as a new question. Although with the same aim, I am being more direct, concise, and clearer so as to hopefully garner more responses.**

I have started learning PHP along with MySQL(complete newbie), and I have created a database with questions and options tables as part of a  quiz app project to help me learn .

I am trying to populate the database by submitting the questions and options through a PHP processed form.

- I  have four rows of fields in the questions section of the form.
- The first row is for the metadata
- The three rows beneath that(each ending with the textbox) represent three separate question rows to be entered in the database.
- The metadata row contains data that I want to fill respective columns in the three question rows once submitted to the database.

This is what I'm trying to get:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LpJP.png

But with the metadata filled out(instead of the zeroes).The metadata should vary based on what is selected in the form for various submissions but be the same for any number of rows inserted at the same time with a given submission.

What I currently have:

[dataentry form]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3S0gu.png
    Question section of form(variable rows) with single field constant metadata

```
        <div class="questinfo">
            <div class="questmetadata">

            <select name="questfield[0][subject_id]">
                <option>BA</option>
                <option>MY</option>
                <option>PA</option>
                <option>BB</option>
                <option>CC</option>
                <option>UA</option>
                <option>HM</option>
                <option>CG</option>

            </select>
             <input name="questfield[0][chapter_id]">

            <input name="questfield[0][topic_id]">
             <input name="questfield[0][is_active]">
            <select name="questfield[0][type]">
                <option>P</option>
                <option>L</option>
            </select>

            <select name="questfield[0][level]">
                <option>1<option>
                <option>2 II<option>
                <option>3<option>
            </select>

            </div>

            <div class="questrow">
            <input  name="questfield[1][questid]">
            <input  name="questfield[1][numero]">
            <textarea  name="questfield[1][question]"></textarea>
            </div>

<div class="questfield">
            <input  name="questfield[2][id]">
            <input  name="questfield[2][numero]">
            <input name= "questfield[2][is_active]">
            <textarea  name="questfield[2][question]"></textarea>
        </div>


            <div class="questrow">
            <input  name="questfield[3][questid]">
            <input  name="questfield[3][numero]">
            <textarea  name="questfield[3][question]"></textarea>
            </div>
```

Options section of form; variable option fields with unique corresponding metadata fields.

```
    <div class="optionfield">
        <input type="text" name ="optionfield[0][optid]">
        <input type="text" name ="optionfield[0][choice]">
        <input type="text" name ="optionfield[0][question_numero]">
        <input type="checkbox" name ="optionfield[0][is_answer]">

        </div>

        <div class="optionfield">
        <input type="text" name ="optionfield[1][optid]">
        <input type="text" name ="optionfield[1][choice]">
        <input type="text" name ="optionfield[1][question_numero]">
        <input type="checkbox" name ="optionfield[1][is_answer]">
        </div>


        <div class="optionfield">
        <input type="text" name ="optionfield[2][optid]">
        <input type="text" name ="optionfield[2][choice]">
        <input type="text" name ="optionfield[2][question_numero]">
        <input type="checkbox" name ="optionfield[2][is_answer]">
        </div>


        <div class="optionfield">
        <input type="text" name ="optionfield[3][optid]">
        <input type="text" name ="optionfield[3][choice]">
        <input type="text" name ="optionfield[3][question_numero]">
        <input type="checkbox" name ="optionfield[3][is_answer]">
        </div>
```

This is the corresponding PHP which only inserts the first row:

```
    $optsql=" INSERT INTO 
    options
    SET
    optid=:optid,
    question_numero=:question_numero,
    choice=:choice,
    is_answer=:is_answer,
    answer_explanation=:answer_explanation";

$questsql=" INSERT INTO questions
            SET
            questid=:questid,
            numero=:numero,
            question=:question,
            subject_id=:subject_id,
            chapter_id=:chapter_id,
            topic_id=:topic_id,
            type=:type,
            level=:level,
            is_active=:is_active

        ";


$optstmt=$clsdb->prepare($optsql);
$queststmt=$clsdb->prepare($questsql);



    foreach($_POST['optionfield'] as $optinput){

    $optdata= array(

        'optid'=>$optinput['optid'],
        'question_numero'=>$optinput['question_numero'],
        'choice'=>$optinput['choice'],
        'answer_explanation'=>$optinput['answer_explanation'],
        'is_answer'=>$optinput['is_answer']);

$optstmt->execute($optdata);


}

foreach($_POST['questfield'] as $questinput){

$questdata= array(

        'questid'=>$questinput['questid'],
        'numero'=>$questinput['numero'],
        'question'=>$questinput['question'],
        'subject_id'=>$questinput['subject_id'],
        'chapter_id'=>$questinput['chapter_id'],
        'topic_id'=>$questinput['topic_id'],
        'type'=>$questinput['type'],
        'level'=>$questinput['level'],
        'is_active'=>$questinput['is_active']);

        $queststmt->execute($questdata);

}
```

How do I do this? Thank you

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code generator ;) And you can hardly find a programmer with the patient to read all the code and make the whole solution. Try splitting your question into smaller, more "attractive" parts (to the programmer flicking through SO) to get an answer quicker (or ever getting one).

Comment: A good tip is to describe what your code does and eliminate all unnecessary code and word.

Comment: I will keep your suggestion in mind for the future. Thank you.